# jQuery Raty duplicates stars when going back and forward using browser's navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-5, raty

I have a question regarding jQuery Raty plugin.

I have a page that lists posts for cars where every post has ratings 1-5. When I go to a specific car post and the go back to the page that show all cars posts using Back arrow in Chrome navigation then the stars gets duplicated. So from 5 stars i get 10 stars.

My code in the car comments index:

```
    $('.review-rating').raty({
      readOnly: true,
      score: function() {
        return $(this).attr('data-score');
      },
      path: '/assets/'
    });
```

Any tips here?

Thank you i advanced.

Answer (score 0):

you can reload to avoid this and perhaps don't forget the preventDefault, and stopPropagation as well. But to avoid the duplication of stars try this `$('.review-rating').raty('reload');`

```
//e.stopPropagation();
//e.preventDefault();
$('.review-rating').raty({
  readOnly: true,
  score: function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-score');
  },
  path: '/assets/'
});
$('.review-rating').raty('reload');
```